# Is it possible using MVVM ViewModel in RecyclerView Adapter or Dialog?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-recyclerview, data-binding, viewmodel

I'm making a function that opens a dialog when I touch the recyclerView item. I put viewModel in adapter and onClick function in viewHolder to open dialog with viewModel.

It looks like this.

`Adapter(viewModel) // Initialize adapter in Activity or ViewModel`

↓

```
class Adapter(viewModel: ViewModel) : ViewModel() {
    inner class ViewHolder() {
        fun onClick(binding: RecyclerViewItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
            Dialog(viewModel) // Open Dialog with viewModel
        }
    }
}
```

Can I use ViewModel in adapter or Dialog? If can't, what should I do? I need to change the data of the ViewModel by receiving the changed value from the Dialog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ViewModels should be limited to activities/fragments, avoid passing it around to whereever you like it. Use liveData to pass events around, for example to pass click events interceptable in the adapter to the activity/fragment to which the viewModel is attached to. Also use liveData to notify your adapter about data changes that occur inside the viewModel. I have created a simple project that reflects your desired outcome, please have a look:

https://github.com/phamtdat/ViewModelForAdapterDemo

key points:

1. data are handled in the viewModel only
2. notify the data changes using liveData
3. update adapter on data changes
4. intercept click events in viewHolder, and forward it to adapter
5. forward click events from adapter to activity that the viewModel is attached to
6. show dialog with corresponding data on click event
7. change the data in dialog logic
8. the result should be: updated recyclerView displaying new data

This way you have clear separation of concerns:
viewModel - handles only data
activity - handles only UI events (in our case the click events of items and showing the dialog)
adapter - handles only correct rendering of item UIs

For simplicity, I didn't use dataBinding, but of course I would if I had time, that way you don't have to update the UI inside the viewHolder, but just pass the model to the binding.

Comment: Sorry for late... It took a long time to understand your code in github. But it helped to solve my problem. Seriously, thanks a lot!

Comment: Makes sense with the separation of concern. But what's the reason you use live data from adapter to activity and callback from view holder to adapter? I would just have a callback from the adapter to activity as well most likely.